# Populate HTML with JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, cakephp

This question has been asked a couple of time here, but I haven't seen any of the responses work for me.

I have this piece of code built with cakePHP which successfully returns the data in JSON format, but I haven't been able to insert this JSON data into HTML div using Javascript.

```
$('.book-click').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var getHotel = $(this).attr('hotel-id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->Html->URL(array('action' => 'postBook')); ?>",
        data: {
            hotel: getHotel
        },
        cache: false,
        dataTye: "json",
        success: function (JSONObject) {
            var myData = "";
            for (var key in JSONObject) {
                if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    myData += JSONObject[key];
                }
            }
            /*console.log(myData);*/
            alert(myData[key]["hotelname"]); //Giving undifined in alert

        }
    });
});
```

And this is the JSON data I get when I log the data on browser console:

```
[
    {
        "id": "11",
        "hotelname": "Sheraton hotel",
        "hoteladdress": "Abule Ikeja",
        "state": "Lagos State",
        "lga": "Ikeja",
        "hotelphone": "65645545454",
        "hotelwebsite": "",
        "adminphone": "6565656565",
        "adminemail": "mail@hotel.com",
        "hotelemail": "",
        "facilities": ",,",
        "roomscategory": "Diplomatic",
        "standardrate": "150000",
        "leanrate": "",
        "aboutHotel": "",
        "requestStatus": "0",
        "createdOn": "1424360902",
        "updatedOn": "1424360902"
    }
]
```

How do I successfully, get this JSON data into HTML. Something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').html(myData[key]["hotelname"]);
```

I tried this, but it's just giving me `Undefined`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Or `$('#myDiv').html(JSONObject[0]["hotelname"]);` without the loop - your loop creates a long string and not an object you can use to index your way into

Comment: @Rory@mplungjan With you guys approaches I still get "undefined".

Comment: so you are not sending application/json but some string that needs to be parsed first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$.each()` to iterate:

```
success: function (JSONObject) {
    $.each(JSONObject, function(k,item){
       $('#myDiv').html(item.hotelname);
    });
}
```

```js
var json = [
    {
        "id": "11",
        "hotelname": "Sheraton hotel",
        "hoteladdress": "Abule Ikeja",
        "state": "Lagos State",
        "lga": "Ikeja",
        "hotelphone": "65645545454",
        "hotelwebsite": "",
        "adminphone": "6565656565",
        "adminemail": "mail@hotel.com",
        "hotelemail": "",
        "facilities": ",,",
        "roomscategory": "Diplomatic",
        "standardrate": "150000",
        "leanrate": "",
        "aboutHotel": "",
        "requestStatus": "0",
        "createdOn": "1424360902",
        "updatedOn": "1424360902"
    }
]

$.each(json, function(i, item){
    $('body').append(item.hotelname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

As per your error, it seems that you either you don't have a valid json or that is a json string. So before loopin you have to parse it:

```
success: function (JSONObject) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(JSONObject); // parse it
    $.each(data, function(k,item){
       $('#myDiv').html(item.hotelname);
    });
}
```

Comment: With approach, this is what I see in browser console:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '394' in [{"id":"11","hotelname":"Sheraton hotel","hoteladdress":"Abule Ikeja","state":"Lagos State","lga":"Ikeja","hotelphone":"65645545454","hotelwebsite":"","adminphone":"6565656565","adminemail":"mail@hotel.com","hotelemail":"","facilities":",,","roomscategory":"Diplomatic","standardrate":"150000","leanrate":"","aboutHotel":"","requestStatus":"0","createdOn":"1424360902","updatedOn":"1424360902"}]

Comment: @Michel See either your json is not json but string. so you need to parse it before using it. like `jQuery.parseJSON(JSONObject)`

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate. You save me time. I just needed to parse the JSON data. This is what I did: var data = $.parseJSON(JSONObject) Then used your approach with $.each() and it works fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData = "";
for (var key in JSONObject) {
   if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       myData += JSONObject[key];
   }
}
```

`myData` here is simply just a `string`. Hence the call `myData[key]["hotelname"]` will return undefined, because you're trying to access something that does not exist.

Why not just use the result as-is from the Ajax call?

Comment: If I use the result as it is returned from ajax, that is whole JSON data. Meanwhile I need for example to get only the value "Sheraton Hotel" which belong to "hotelname".